# So that ... would

Tags: conjunctions

I wanted to use the **"so that ... would"** phrase and used it like:

**I want so that a car would drive**

But I was told it was wrong. The sense i am putting in all of this is like here:

**I wish you wre here**

**I want you to be here**

Can we say the same about the car?

**I wish the car drove**

**I want the car to drive**

But the original variant I got from this example:

**We left a message with his neighbour so that he would know we’d called**

Here the "so that ... would"construction works but in my example it doesn't.

**I want so that a car drives**

Comment: What do you want to say? Your sentences do not really make sense. The say "I want" but there is nothing to want. "So that a car drives / would drive" is also a meaningless fragment.

Comment: I want to use it the same as it's here:"We left a message with her  secretary so that she would know we have come."

Comment: Please edit the question and add the information in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are interested constructs built on the following pattern:

> (Subject) (action) (details) so that (purpose).

In your model sentence:

> (We) (left) (a message with her secretary) so that (she would know we have come).

---

> - **I want** (what?) so that **a car would drive**
> - **I want** (what?) so that **a car drives**

These sentences break the pattern badly:

- "want" needs (details): what do you want?
- "a car would drive" / "a car drives": does not make much sense, at least not as a purpose.

---

One way to repair your sentences is:

> (I) (want) (the technologies to advance faster) so that (cars could be driven autonomously).

---

In some cases, the details after the verb are not needed:

> I work so that I can have money.

---

> - I wish a car drove
> - I want a car to drive

They both sound incomplete, some details are missing. Drive how? Where?

> - I want you to come

It is OK.

---

> or it's still horrible?

These were exactly my thoughts, but I was hesitant to express them :)

Don't worry, nobody was ever born knowing English perfectly.

Comment: Can we then change it for "I wish a car drove" without any other details? Or for "I want a car to drive" like in "I want you to come".

Well, I am glad that it's the internet, Having said something terrible like that I would burn with shame I am a perfectionist and all mistakes increase my "English Depression":)

Comment: There is no need for: shame, perfectionism, depression ;)

Comment: As I commented earlier, you can get better information if you add details to the original question ;) Including the new sentences.